# How to ignore source text/link while using caption in tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I want to use caption as title for my image posts in tumblr, but as you know tumblr puts in the Source link within the caption.

Now, I could negative margin the caption area but not every post is supposed to have source.

Is there any way to ignore the source text/link in caption (which can be used as a javascript string)?

Thanks

These are the instances:
Using `{Caption}` produces

- "(Source: [sourcelink], via [vialink])" if no caption available - this is what needs to be hidden/ not displayed
- "(via [vialink])" if no source or caption available - also needs hiding
- "[sourcelink]: [caption]" if caption available - no hiding needed
- "[caption]" if you are the caption source - also shouldn't be hidden

Comment: No, at this time, there is no way to optionally ignore that part of the caption. Playing with margins is messy and unnecessary when you could use javascript to remove the text you don't want. Of course, this would be something that is done after the caption is loaded so there might be a screen flicker, but I don't see another way around it since Tumblr does not put any CSS classes on that additional p tag that would allow you to change the display.

Comment: Can you add a live example of the caption / issue.

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks, added an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Tumblr very well, but at least you can load jQuery in your page and use regular expressions to remove the elements you don't want.

Plus you don't have to set any margin to strange values.

The jQuery would look like this :

```
$('.caption').each(function() {
  // Get the html() of the .caption div
  var text = $(this).html();

  // Look for (Source...) and remove it
  var regex = /\(Source:.*via(.*)\)+/ig;
  text = text.replace(regex, '');

  // Look for (via...) and remove it
  regex = /\(via(.*)\)+/ig;
  text = text.replace(regex, '');

  // Finally set the html() of the .caption div
  $(this).html(text);
});
```

Look at this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/atd5erbh/2/

Comment: And since this is used on Tumblr, further replacing "`Source`" with "`{lang:Source}`" will make this work for users on non-english setups.

Comment: That's a very clean and fine solution, worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

ya just put this in:

```
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}
```